# Can I change a the PBS script file of a job that is on hold in TORQUE Resource Manager?

Tags: pbs, torque

I have a couple of jobs in the locked jobs queue with the status `UserHold`. Is there a way to edit the PBS file that launched them? I used `qalter` before to change the walltime, group or name. This time I want to change the parameters of the aprun call in the submitted PBS file.

Comment: torque copies the script into its own temporary storage, therefore you could find and edit it there. The script name would be changed to the jobid. However I would try as much as I could to delete and resubmit instead.

Comment: Do you happen to know where should I look for the copy of my PBS file? My job is currently on hold and I don't want to resubmit it because of it's size (>50% of the entire machine).

Comment: On my torque installation which is version 3.0.5 the script is stored under `/var/lib/torque/server_priv/jobs/<jobname>.SC`. I suppose this file is only writeable by the Torque server root.

Answer (score 2):

Typically speaking you shouldn't do this. The correct procedure would be to delete your job and submit a new one with the new job script.

Comment: I ended up doing so.Nevertheless I want to find a way to check the job script after it's been queued without having to make a manual copy of it each time I launch a job.

Comment: You can check the script using a submit filter.